# Create Application Password when User Registers

Tags: rest-api, user-registration, password

I can successfully create application passwords using the [POST /wp/v2/users/<user_id>)/application-passwords endpoint](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/application-passwords/#create-a-application-password) but is there a way to have WordPress create an application password for a user when they successfully register on the site? And have that application password included in their registration confirmation email?